# find index of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

here is my **html** code:

```
<div class="more-content">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="post">post 1</div>
    <div class="post">post 2</div>
    <div class="post">post 3</div>
</div>
```

Here is **jquery**:

```
$(".post").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

i don't want to consider the input text while trying to get index of div inside of main div.Hence clicking on post 3 must show 2 and not 3.How to do that??

here is the jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/16/

Comment: so you want to show: onclick post 3 show 2, onclick post 2 show 1, onclick post 1 show 0 ?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/26/ and API: http://api.jquery.com/index/#index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `index()` this way:

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('.post');
    alert(index);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `$('.post').index(this)`

check: http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/18/

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NDySY/21/

`div.post` means only div with class `post`

```
$("div.post").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('div.post');
    alert(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in class **post** click event fetch index as follow:

```
var index=$('.post').index(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the number of post then subtract it by the index. You index function should also have a parameter for the selector where it should be relative to

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('.post');
    var comp = $('.post').length - index;

    alert(comp);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/24/

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this.**

```
$(".post").click(function() {

    var eventCreator=this;

    $('.post').each(function(index,value){

        var currentDiv=value;

        if(eventCreator==currentDiv)
        {
        alert(index);
            //Do what ever you want to do with index
        }


    });

});
```

Check the JS Fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/27/)**